# Can someone please help me understand the role of Google Cloud Endpoints for web clients in a webapp?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After reading the documentation for Cloud Endpoints, I can appreciate their usefulness in providing access to the App Engine webapp from Android and iOS platforms, but why would anyone use them for Javascript clients on their website when the website can directly access the App Engine app instances?

Maybe I am missing something really obvious being a novice! Many thanks to anyone who can educate me on this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppEngine instances grant authenticated direct access to only JavaScript clients loaded from the website of that same instance.  Endpoints provide a way for JavaScript clients hosted elsewhere to authenticate and access the instance content.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Would there be any advantage of using Endpoint API in the same website which serves the app accessed through Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: The advantage would be mainly that you can perform more processing in the client using the JavaScript language.  If it is a rich interactive application that improves responsiveness.  The browser client can access Datastore, Google Cloud Storage, Mail, Url Fetch and Task Queues.  But the client user can see what your application is thinking with the browser's developer tools or View Source.